# Could the IPG parameter in Robocopy cause TCP/IP packet problems if it is too high?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, tcpip, file-transfer, robocopy

I need to throttle a robocopy transfer to limit bandwidth usage. It is already set to 1500 (/IPG:1500). I would like to increase this IPG to around 2000 (or more) in order to lower even more the bandwidth usage. Is there a chance that it could cause some packet loss because of TCP/IP timeouts, etc. ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robocopy's IPG switch value is measured in milliseconds, so 1500 = 1.5s and 2000 = 2s. In any network with normal TCP settings and operation, a two second gap in a TCP conversation is /very/ common. Have you experienced any issues with packet loss? If you have, it's most likely caused by something other than your IPG value.